# How to obtain packets as soon as sending a frame?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.265

I am experimenting with the encoder example. According to the FFmpeg [encoding and decoding API overview](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.3/group__lavc__encdec.html), the codec might accept multiple input frames without returning a packet, until its internal buffers are filled.

Is there a way to receive a packet as soon as I send a frame?

Specifically, I am using libx265, and the first frame is always an I frame (key frame) which can be encoded without later frames. However, I have to send quite a few following frames to obtain the first packet, and this leads to severe latency.

I tried to look into [AVCodecContext](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/ed6549887a1969636b30295b3da87313b7c46864/libavcodec/avcodec.h) structure to find a corresponding option but failed to find something related.

Thankful for any help you can offer.